# windows phone page loading speed

Tags: windows-phone

From one Page to the next Page,there is one property which is bound in the UI, and this proporty needs to take one waste time opration, so the page is not coming for a long time, is there any way to improve the speed.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e) {
    string value = string.Empty;
    IDictionary<string, string> queryString = this.NavigationContext.QueryString;
    if (queryString.ContainsKey("Type"))
    {
        this.Type = queryString["Type"];
        new Thread(() => {
            mtv.AddDistanceForList();
        }).Start();

    }
    else
    {
            GetMovieThreater();
    }
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e); }  

private void GetMovieThreater() {
    string movieId = PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["MovieId"] as string;

    mtv.SelectThreaterByMovie(movieId);
    mtv.AddDistanceForList();  }
```

In View Model like this:

```
private ObservableCollection<Threater> threaters; public ObservableCollection<Threater> Threaters {
    get { return threaters; }
    set
    {
        if (threaters != value)
        {
            threaters = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Threaters");
        }
    } }

private CollectionViewSource filteredThreater; public CollectionViewSource FilteredThreater {
    get { return filteredThreater; }
    set
    {
        filteredThreater = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("FilteredThreater");
    } } This function wate time!!! public void SelectThreaterByMovie(string movieId) {
    Threaters.Clear();

    if(MovieDataAllMovies.Threaters!=null)
    {
      foreach(var i in MovieDataAllMovies.MoviePlans){
          if (i.MovieId == movieId)
          {
              MovieDataAllMovies.Threaters.ForEach((e) =>
              {
                  if (i.TheaterId == e.Tid.ToString())
                  {
                      Threaters.Add(e);
                  }
              });
          }
      }
      Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
      {
          this.FilteredThreater.Source = Threaters;
      });    } }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a very good article about how to handle this sort of situation with a Performance Progress Bar when interacting with long running Web Service calls [available here](http://dan.clarke.name/tag/performance-progress-bar/) with sample code at the bottom of the article page.

To quote Dan Clarke, "I quite like to have a global Performance Progress Bar in my Windows Phone 7 apps so the user has a consistent frame of reference when I’m interacting with web services. The requirements are simple, a progress bar that appears on all pages without any special requirements (ie. no custom controls, special code snippets, etc.). It should be managed in one place, and be easy to extend. Fortunately the extreme flexibility Silverlight offers makes this a doddle:" [Source](http://dan.clarke.name/tag/performance-progress-bar/)

This option will at least give your using an idea that the page is loading at the bare minimum.